# How to show only two column in ipad using bootstrap grid

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I am trying to show two column in iPad but it is coming 3 column. How to write bootstrap CSS for that. I have written media query for that. col-lg-3 col-md-4 are not working properly for iPad. I do not know which col add to the class. If anyone knows please help to find the solution.

```
<div class="container px-5">
<div class="row"> 
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="filters-content">

   <div class="row grid">
     <div *ngFor="let item of result" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
       
     </div> 
   </div>

 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-selvam-ecommerce-task-d1rhft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdirectives%2Fproductslist.dir.ts

Comment: Bootstrap’s “tablet” classes use the “sm” sizing. Instead of using md (Desktop) and lg (literally “Larger Desktop”), try playing around with the sm ones.

Comment: @HamzaAssada: Can you update in the stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

I see, in that case, you can use the col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 classes to achieve the desired layout. This will make each item take up 12 columns on extra small screens (i.e., screens with a width of less than 576px), 6 columns on small screens (i.e., screens with a width of 576px or more), and 4 columns on medium screens (i.e., screens with a width of 768px or more).
Here's an updated code snippet with the changes:

```
<div class="container px-5">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="filters-content">
        <div class="row grid">
          <div *ngFor="let item of result" class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <!-- Your item content here -->
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This should display one item per row on extra small screens, two items per row on small screens, and four items per row on medium and large screens.

Comment: I am expecting like for mobile one col, for iPad two col, For desktop 4 col. It means  for mobile one card per row, for iPad two card per row, For desktop 4 card per row

Comment: You have any solution?

Comment: I edited my answer, I hope that's what you want, if not, let me know